# Why would signing credentials from a RSA-SHA512 X509Certificate2 appear to be RSA-SHA256?

Tags: .net, certificate, rsa, sha, x509certificate2

Given a public/private key pair PFX file created from the following commands:

```
makecert.exe -r -n "CN=TEST" -pe -sv TEST.pvk -a sha512 -len 2048 -b 01/01/2014 -e 12/31/2075 TEST.cer
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk TEST.pvk -spc TEST.cer -pfx TEST.pfx
```

The following C# code:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("TEST.pfx");
Console.WriteLine(cert.SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName);

var creds = new X509SigningCredentials(cert);
Console.WriteLine(creds.SignatureAlgorithm);
Console.WriteLine("Key size: {0}", creds.SigningKey.KeySize / 8);
```

Results in this:

```
sha512RSA
http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256
Key size: 256
```

What I am confused about is why the signing credentials are coming out as SHA256 when the cert was created SHA512?  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Just to note: makecert.exe tool is deprecated and you should avoid it in supported environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are probably misunderstanding is where the hashing algorithms are used. The first one is used during the creation of the signature *over* the certificate. The second one is the hashing algorithm that is used during signing with the private key that belongs to the certificate. That one seems to default to SHA-256.

Note that Microsoft is actually confusing hashing algorithms with signature algorithms. Maybe that once made some sense when everybody was still only using PKCS#1 v1.5 style signatures, but now it just makes them look stupid.